# Asp.net grid view bind to dynamic select query

Tags: c#, asp.net, gridview, datagridview

I want to pass the sql select query from the code behind and based on that query, data should be automatically fill in the grid view. The select query will be different i.e. it can select any tables or views. My code is as follows.

**CodeBehind**

```
Protected void ExecuteButton_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
   string sql = SqlQueryTextBox.Text;
   SqlDataSource1.SelectCommand = sql;
   GridView1.Databind();
}
```

**Asp Markup**

```
<asp:GridView ID="GridView1" runat="server"
    DataSourceID="SqlDataSource1" AutoGenerateColumns="true">

</asp:GridView>
```

But nothing is loaded in grid view. Upto now I have used grid view only to bind single table and its columns. Is there any mistake in my logic? How can I fill the grid with dynamic data?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This works fine for me...

```
<asp:SqlDataSource ID="SqlDataSource1"  runat="server" ConnectionString="Data Source=*******Initial Catalog=*******;Persist Security Info=True;User ID=*******;Password=*******" ></asp:SqlDataSource>
<div>
    <asp:TextBox ID="SqlQueryTextBox" runat="server" ></asp:TextBox>
    <asp:Button ID="ExecuteButton"  OnClick="ExecuteButton_Click" runat="server" Text="Execute"/>
</div>
<div>
    <asp:GridView ID="GridView1" runat="server" DataSourceID="SqlDataSource1" AutoGenerateColumns="true" />
</div>
```

..

```
protected void ExecuteButton_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
SqlDataSource1.SelectCommand = SqlQueryTextBox.Text;
GridView1.DataBind();
}
```

Ps. I used "SELECT * FROM information_schema.tables"  as my select statement

I think you need to check your connection string. and then get back to us.

Answer (score 0):

```
string sql = SqlQry.Text;
SqlDataSource1.SelectCommand = sql;
SqlDataSource1 .Select (DataSourceSelectArguments .Empty );
Gv_1.DataBind();
```

Comment: I think it would be more helpful for the OP and further visitors, whenn you add some explaination to your intension.

Comment: questioner add query dynamically so after selectcommand bind to sqldatasource and then bind to gridview